# What is the difference between host_check_live command and Ping service

Tags: nagios

We are using Nagios based Op5 to monitors servers.

Do we need to have Ping service too for servers as I guess host_check_live `(command: $USER2$/check_host -H $HOSTADDRESS$)`  command already uses Ping to see if it alive.

**Isn't Ping redundant?**

Comment: Side note: you'll want to use check_icmp instead of check_ping if you have more than a few hundred hosts. It must be setuid root (just like the ping binary) but is about 10x faster.

Answer (score 3):

At least on my NAGIOS installation, `check_host-alive` actually runs `check-ping`:

```
define command{
        command_name    check-host-alive
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
        }
```

There are two things that make me think that defining this as a check separate to stock `check_ping` is not redundant.

Firstly, those thresholds are crazily high.  For no normal server am I happy with an RTT of 2900ms or packet losses of 70%.  Those thresholds are really only useful as a test of whether a server is actually, genuinely down.  Here's an example of thresholds when I actually care about the **values** returned:

```
check_ping!200.0,20%!600.0,60%
```

So there's a **quantitative** difference between the way PING is used to check host availability, and when used a service in its own right, and that alone justifies making a distinction between ping-as-host-up-test and ping-as-link-quality-test.

Secondly, some of my monitored hosts can't be PINGed, sometimes for reasons outside my control.  In those cases, I'll use a simple TCP connectivity check to a monitored port, or in one case [the output of traceroute](https://serverfault.com/questions/629853/nagios-host-availability-test-for-host-that-cant-be-pinged-wont-talk-to-me-b).

**Edit**: it just occurred to me that you might be asking "*why PING a host to check if it's up if we're only going to PING it again as a service check*".  If that's your question, then reason 1 above still applies.  But also, I often don't care about PING as a service check - poor quality links will show up in the many other services that are monitored.  So PING's not redundant in most of those cases.  If you don't care about the output of PING other than a test for host-up, don't run it as a service check either.

Answer (score 0):

The default nagios host check is based on ping.  If you have implemented a separate service check for ping that would be redundant.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I agree - see above!

Comment: Fixing your basic host check to have appropriate sensitivity seems like a better bet than having redundant checks.

Comment: I'm sorry if I've been unclear.  When I use it as a host check, I really don't care about latency, high packet losses, etc.  I only care if the host is down beyond all reasonable doubt, so that I get one HOST DOWN alert instead of 22 SERVICE DOWN alerts.  When I use it as a link quality check, as a service, I do care about those things.  I'm trying to determine different data when I use `check_ping` in two different ways.  Is that any clearer?

Comment: Now it is clearer.  I don't use nagios for marginal network monitoring.  smokeping or something else that can show you the history seems like a better fit to those issues.  But if you insist on doing it all in nagios, then you are not as redundant as you initially appeared.